# Why can't I push this node that takes from my BST into this stack?

Tags: c++, stack, binary-search-tree

How's it's structured .h:

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
    template <typename> friend class BST;
    public:
        Node(T p) : data(p), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
        ~Node() {}
    private:
        T data; // The holder of PACKET.
        Node *rlink, *llink;

};

template <typename T>
class BST {
public:
    BST();
    void insert(T &p);
    void inorderTraversal() const;
private:
    Node<T> * root; 
};
```

This is the suspected function that I will be using and where the problem occurs:

```
void inorderTraversal() const{
    stack <T> *iterStack;
    Node <T> *currentNode = root;
    iterStack->push(currentNode);
}
```

Error:

> 'void std::stack>>::push(const
>   Packet &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Node *' to 'Packet &&'

How can I fix this so that the stack can take in my nodes?

Note that Packet is an object that gets taken in by Node's private member `T data`.

Packet.h (for reference):

```
class Packet {
public:
    Packet(int partId, string description, double price, int partCount) :
        partId(partId), description(description), price(price), partCount(partCount) {}
    int getPartId() const { return partId; }
    string getDescription() const { return description; }
    double getPrice() const { return price; }
    int getPartCount() const { return partCount; }
private:
    int partId;
    string description;
    double price;
    int partCount;
};
```

Update:

Tried

```
template <typename T>
void BST<T>::inorderTraversal() const{
    stack <Node<T> *> iterStack;
    Node <T> *currentNode = root;
    iterStack->push(currentNode);
}
```

Got errors:

> 'std::stack *,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>' does not
>   have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
>
> 'std::stack  *,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::push':
>   left operand has 'class' type, use '.'

Comment: Clearly `stack <T> *iterStack;` (an indeterminate pointer) followed by `iterStack->push(currentNode);` isn't going to work regardless. But if you're `std::stack` needs to hold `Node<T>*` rather than `T`, then... do that?

Comment: Do you mean like this "stack <Node<T> *> iterStack?" I tried that. It doesn't work. I got errors, look up at my update. I'm not sure how to configure this so I can put it in my stack. Any idea?

Comment: Your update is now using the wrong member access operator. It should be `iterStack.push(currentNode);` (note the dot rather than arrow).

Comment: I'm sorry to have to say this, but you must get a firmer grasp of the basics of the language before you attempt a project of this complexity. I suggest a linked list as a good starter exercise.

Comment: @Beta, I have already done the linked list. I actually haven't used C++ in more than ~2 years or so? I'm trying to review and this is for school purposes. Aside from that, I've rarely dealt with templates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, substitute the template parameters in your head and consider the code that results. For example, if `T` is to be `Packet` for your purposes here, then this:

```
std::stack<T> *iterStack;
Node <T> *currentNode = root;
iterStack->push(currentNode);
```

would be synonymous with

```
std::stack<Packet> *iterStack;
Node <Packet> *currentNode = root;
iterStack->push(currentNode);
```

Obviously this code is cut down (only because obviously *yours* is), and one could sanely question whether `iterStack` needs to be dynamic in the first place; see the aside it highly likely does *not*).

Regardless, clearly a `std::stack<Packet>` cannot hold `Node<Packet>*` objects; but a `std::stack< Node<Packet>* >` *can*. I.e.

```
std::stack< Node<T> > *iterStack;
Node <T> *currentNode = root;
iterStack->push(currentNode);
```

---

Aside, it is likely your stack doesn't need to be itself-dynamic in the first place.

```
std::stack< Node<T>* > stk;
Node <T> *currentNode = root;
stk.push(currentNode);
```